# Withhold first app from release on App Store?

Tags: app-store

I haven't finished submitting my Tax and ABN (Australian Business Number) as that's still being under review. I don't want to submit my app and be released for free.

I'd like to submit my app for review during this time (hopefully get it approved) and then release it as soon as I get my ABN.

Maybe I'm missing it on iTunes Connect but I only know of the Version Release Control for existing apps. Is there anything for new apps to say when my Apps gets to be released? Or is it just the "Availability Date" under Pricing and Rights?

I figured there'd be something more flexible as I don't know how long the review will take exactly.. yeah i realise its about 7-10 days but I also have to wait for my ABN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it Out from all Markts in the Rights and pricing of itunesconnect.apple.com